# Hide main div when a specific class is not found with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, hide

I am trying to hide the main div ('product-block-list__item product-block-list__item--content size__chart') when the class ('ks-chart-container') is not in the page.

(No jQuery if possible)

---

Here is the container with ('ks-chart-container').

```
<div class="product-block-list__item product-block-list__item--content size__chart">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="card__collapsible-button" data-action="toggle-collapsible" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="block-template--14697163096134__main-092edfe6-4684-4f51-970d-dfb11469ca43">
      <span class="card__title heading h3">Size chart</span>
      <span class="plus-button plus-button--large"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="block-template--14697163096134__main-092edfe6-4684-4f51-970d-dfb11469ca43" class="card__collapsible" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="card__collapsible-content">
        <div class="rte text--pull">
          <div id="KiwiSizingChart" class=" kiwiSizingLoaded">
            <div class="ks-chart-container sizing-chart-container">
              <div class="ks-chart-tab-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ks-calculator-container sizing-calculator-container ks-calculator-inject hide"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is the container without ('ks-chart-container').

```
<div class="product-block-list__item product-block-list__item--content size__chart">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="card__collapsible-button" data-action="toggle-collapsible" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="block-template--14697163096134__main-092edfe6-4684-4f51-970d-dfb11469ca43">
      <span class="card__title heading h3">Size chart</span>
      <span class="plus-button plus-button--large"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="block-template--14697163096134__main-092edfe6-4684-4f51-970d-dfb11469ca43" class="card__collapsible" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="card__collapsible-content">
        <div class="rte text--pull">
          <div id="KiwiSizingChart" class=" kiwiSizingLoaded"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using:

`.ks-chart-container:empty .product-block-list__item.product-block-list__item--content.size__chart { display: none; }`

But did not work. (Excuse my coding, I'm a beginner).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not possible to style an element based on its children with CSS.

You can do that using some vanilla Javascript (not jQuery), getting all the elements with the **.ks-chart-container** class and setting the CSS attribute *display: none* on its parent element with the **.product-block-list__item** class:

```
for (const ksChart of document.querySelectorAll('.ks-chart-container')) {
  ksChart.closest('.product-block-list__item').style.display = 'none';
}
```

If you don't want to use Javascript, depending the programming language, framework, etc. you're using, check on your template if **.ks-chart-container** exists and then, display the code or not depending on it. Maybe this is the best option...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the **[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** method which returns a Nodelist for the specified selector.

Assign a variable using **querySelectorAll** with the `ks-chart-container` class. You can determine if the page contains the specified class name by looking at the `length` property returned by **querySelectorAll**.

If the page does not contain the class `ks-chart-container` it will return a `length` value of 0. If so, hide the main div.

If the `ks-chart-container` class already exists on the page, the `length` value will be greater than 0 and you can keep the main div in view.

Run the code snippet below to see this in action. I've added notes in the code to help you understand.

Please let me know if this helps, or if you have questions.

```js
//declare variable for div with class 'ks-chart-container' using querySelectorAll
var ksChartContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.ks-chart-container');


//declare variable for main div that you want to hide
var mainDiv = document.querySelector('.product-block-list__item.product-block-list__item--content.size__chart')


//this is a function will look for the 'ks-chart-container' div, if the div doesn't exist, it will hide the mainDiv
function hideMainDiv() {
  //if length property of ksChartContainer is less than 1, hide the main div
  if (ksChartContainer.length < 1) {
    console.log('ks-chart-container class does not exist on the page')
    mainDiv.style.display = 'none'
    //if length property of ksChartContainer is greater than 0, keep the main div in view
  } else if ((ksChartContainer.length > 0)) {
    mainDiv.style.display = 'block'
    console.log('ks-chart-container class exists on the page')
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-block-list__item product-block-list__item--content size__chart">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="card__collapsible-button" data-action="toggle-collapsible" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="block-template--14697163096134__main-092edfe6-4684-4f51-970d-dfb11469ca43">
      <span class="card__title heading h3">Size chart</span>
      <span class="plus-button plus-button--large"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="block-template--14697163096134__main-092edfe6-4684-4f51-970d-dfb11469ca43" class="card__collapsible" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="card__collapsible-content">
        <div class="rte text--pull">
          <div id="KiwiSizingChart" class=" kiwiSizingLoaded"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--The section below is for example purposes-->
<br/><br/><br/>
<div>
  <p>Click the button below to run the hideMainDiv function. If the "ks-chart-container" class isn't found on the page, the main div will be hidden.</p>
  <button onclick="hideMainDiv()">Click</button>
</div>
```